# Python cellular automata to solve a 'spreading' simulation

Tags: python, cellular-automata

So, I've got a nested list of 50 rows and columns (and 50 lists in the nested list) .In the nested list there are random '1' , '0' , and ''. I want it such that at the beginning, a random '0' is turned into a '1' and that '1' turns other '0' into 1'. Also, after a time step, I want the '1' to convert all the '0' surrounding it into '1'. I've seen online that cellular automata is one way to solve this problem, but I don't know how to do it without using numpy. In this example shown in the picture, TRUE would be represented with '1' and FALSE is represented as "0". load_bushfire returns a nested list of '1','0' and'' which are pixels that represents a map. There's no need to visualise the map as I have a code for it. Any suggestions ?
[image]

Comment: Hi Ryan, it would be simpler to answer your question if you provide a couple of examples, because it is hard to understand actual transformations. It sound like cellular automata is the right choice. Can you add more info to your question?

Comment: Artem, I've edited it additional information. I hope you can help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

To iterate over all pixels surrounding elements `a[ i ],[ j]` the pattern is `a[i+k][j+l] for k in [-1, 0, 1] for l in [-1, 0, 1 ] if k or l` well you have to check boundaries i guess.

For particularly complex rules you might need two nested list (matrix) for more fair simulation.  At each step  you will compute new nested list based on previous based on whatever rules you have. For an example see https://github.com/mwharrisjr/Game-of-Life . Once each step processed you render new nested list. Personally I think you would be better with ternary logic. Fuel, nofuel, fire (blue, white, red)